# When using Apache as a reverse proxy server, can environment variables that were set using SetEnvIf be accessed when processing a response?

Tags: apache-2.2

In other words, a user sends a request to my application which is behind a reverse proxy. The reverse proxy intercepts the request and sets an environment variable `aaa` using `SetEnvIf`. The reverse proxy then passes the request to my application. My application generates a response and sends it back to the reverse proxy. Can I now use the `aaa` variable somewhere in the response or is the variable only scoped to the request?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. The implementation will vary based on the server-side language.
Here's an example with PHP:

```
$_SERVER['SOME_ENV_VARIABLE']
```

> Use the apache SetEnv directive to set arbitrary $_SERVER variables in
>   your vhost or apache config.

More info. can be found here: http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php

Comment: Thanks for the response. I know you can access the variable via PHP - I was asking if I can access a variable that was set by the reverse proxy when a request was made (using SetEnvIf) when the reverse proxy is processing the response from the application. Basically does the reverse proxy maintain the state of the variables for corresponding requets/responses?